# EventSource is not writing to SQL database

Tags: c#, logging, azure-sql-database, eventsource

I am using EventSource to log my events to SQL database by EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging,

Following is test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Log_Test()
    {
        var eventListener = new ObservableEventListener();

        var sqlListener = SqlDatabaseLog.CreateListener("Instance", CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnectionStringTrace"), "Traces");
        eventListener.EnableEvents(ApplicationEventSource.Log, EventLevel.LogAlways, Keywords.All);

        ApplicationEventSource.Log.ComponentNotLoaded("Milind", "Cheeta", "Core");
```

And ApplicationEventSource class derives from EventSource with following method

```
        [Event(2,
        Keywords = Keywords.Component,
        Message = "Component: {2} not successfully loaded for user: {0} on machine: {1}",
        Task = Tasks.Load,
        Opcode = EventOpcode.Start,
        Level = EventLevel.Error)]
    public void ComponentNotLoaded(string userName, string machineName, string componentName)
    {
        WriteEvent(2, userName, machineName, componentName);
    }
```

I am not getting error while WriteEvent but nothing is being log to table **Trace**

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full ApplicationEventSource class.

if you alter the method like this:

```
public void ComponentNotLoaded(string userName, string machineName, string componentName)
{
    if(IsEnabled())
        WriteEvent(2, userName, machineName, componentName);
}
```

will WriteEvent be called? If not, something is wrong in the structure. Try validating the EventSource class using the Event Source Analyzer.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774985(v=pandp.20).aspx#_Checking_an_event

Also, normal procedure to setup the database sink is like this:

```
eventListener.LogToSqlDatabase(
                Environment.MachineName,
                sqlConnectionString,
            );
```